# Get the last array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any method to get the last array in javascript on submit event in run time.

For eg:

If I click on submit button it generate following array:

```
["0-50", "51-100"]
```

Again I add some fields and click on submit button it generate following output:

```
["0-50", "51-100", "101-120"]
```

I want to get the last array data. Is it possible?

Comment: This is unclear because the answer depends on the app. If your app has a backend storage layer, the front end could send an ajax request for the previous submission.  Alternatively, your front end could be caching historical events in localStorage.  If your app is really old and submit brings up a new page, all the javascript variables are lost between refreshes.  In that case, the backend needs to insert whatever is needed from history into the page.  We can't tell which of these issues exist because they are not in the posted question. Please edit and post a minimally sufficient example app.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the last item with the [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of an array and subtracting one for getting the last inserted index.

> The array **`length`** property sets or returns the number of elements in an array. It represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

```js
var array = ["0-50", "51-100", "101-120"];

console.log(array[array.length - 1]);
```

Comment: But i  have to pass whole array bcoz i have to perform some function with this. so i just wanna ignore previous value & just get the last array data on last submit button

Comment: please edit your question and insert the part for sumbmitting as well to the question.